# Android youtube player resumed after user touching push to talk button

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Our app is using the Android youtube player to play the youtube videos. There is one strange thing we noticed:

- user play a youtube video
- user pauses it by clicking the "play/pause" button
- youtube video paused
- user touches push to talk button trying to say something
- the youtube video automatically resumes

I wonder is Android youtube player using android media player? why it automatically resumes when user touches PPT button? I looked at the code, we don't resume the youtube player or even resume the media player.

Comment: Can you provide code samples/snippets of your source?